# How do i make a bot that clicks every few seconds

Tags: python

I want to write a code that clicks in a specific position every few seconds and i dont know how to do it. I need someone to help me

Comment: What do you want to click? Website element or something else?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!, Unfortunately, This question is a little bit too vague, it asks very generally for what would constitute a tutorial instead of asking a specific question. Therefore it is not suitable for stackoverflow as Stackoverflow is not a tutorial provider or a free code writing service, I recommend new users to review the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of stackoverflow for tips on asking questions that are well-suited for the site and best enable the community to provide helpful feedback. Goodluck :)

Comment: Show the code you wrote so far, or at least cite the source that made you think that is possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/control-mouse-python) library to move and click with the mouse.

In order to do it repeatedly a simple loop will work. [This is a link to python documentation on loops.](https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops)

To do it every few seconds you will also need to add a delay in the loop. The sleep function should do this for you. [This is a link to the documentation for sleep.](https://realpython.com/python-sleep/)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check [PyAutoGui](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) and use [pyautogui.click(x, y)](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#mouse-clicks), just put it in a `for` or `while` loop with a delay:

```
import time

import pyautogui as pag


def click(pos: tuple[int, int], times: int, interval: float) -> None:
    for i in range(times):
        pag.click(x=pos[0], y=pos[1])
        time.sleep(interval)  # in milliseconds
```

PS.: You don't have to worry about type hinting, but it's always a good practice.